# Run Hadoop Application

Tags: hadoop

1. Can a Hadoop App be booted on any one of the cluster nodes, irrelvantly to the node type?
2. Should the App be booted only on one of the nodes?
3. Does Hadoop move the code to the proper nodes near to the data?
4. Is Java RMI used for the purpose of moving the code?

**@EDIT**

On each Hadoop installed node, who are the master nodes should be explicitly assigned, by setting `fs.default.name` of `core-site.xml` for the `Namenode` and `mapred.job.tracker` of `mapred-stie.xml` for the `Jobtracker`.

However, the slave nodes `Datanode` and `Tasktracer` can't be explicitly assigned, can they?

Instead, they dynamically join the cluster when its Hadoop dameon starts, or leave the cluster when the daemon stops , right?

If a Hadoop installed node is neither assigned to a master nor its hadoop daemon runs, it can still launch a Hadoop App, right?

**@2nd EDIT**

It seems that the slave nodes should also be explicitly listed in `conf/slaves` file on the master nodes in order to collectively be started or stopped over there.

Comment: #1 is actually a common question for new developers in my larger clusters. There is a common misconception that you want to run jobs on the jobtracker node, which is one of the worst places to run a job.

Answer (score 4):

1. Hadoop jobs can fire from anywhere, as long as the `core-site.xml` configuration is set properly. This doesn't have to be a data node or a master node. On larger clusters it us customary to have a "query node" that doesn't have any of the Hadoop daemons running on it.
2. It's not a big deal to have the job fire on specific node, unless your program does some sort of heavy pre- or post-computation outside of MapReduce. If they are, you want to keep these on their own node. Running the jobs on a data node is better than running the job on the master nodes.
3. Hadoop replicates the jar files all over the place so the code is available locally. I don't think this uses RMI, but I could be wrong. In the end, it's all abstracted away from the user and is not something you need to pay attention to.

Comment: Hadoop ships with its own RPC mechanism, so there is no RMI.

Comment: `Hadoop jobs can fire from anywhere, as long as the core-site.xml configuration is set properly.` - The client submitting the job should know where the JobTracker and the NameNode are, so fs.default.name for NN and mapred.job.tracker for JT have to be set. These are the minimum parameters. It doesn't matter if it's core-site.xml or mycore-site.xml. The configurations have to be passed to the client running the job using the -D option or from a file.

Comment: `It's not a big deal to have the job fire on specific node, unless your program does some sort of heavy pre- or post-computation outside of MapReduce.` - The InputSplits are calculated and the metadata about the InputData is copied to HDFS on the client along with the job jar. If too many jobs aren't submitted or the InputSplit calculation is not CPU intensive, then a dumb  client should be good. MAPREDUCE-207 is for moving the InputSplit calculation from the client to the cluster, yet to be committed.

Comment: @Praveen Sripati: Do you mean that the `InputData` for a `MapReduce` job will always firstly be converted to `InputSplit` chunks, so that they can be  distributed to feed a number of sub `Map` tasks? Now the calculation is done on the client, but can be moved into the cluster in a later Hadoop release?

Comment: There are no InputSplit chunks, there is no data conversion and the data resides where it was. InputSplits are **logical** seperation of the input data across record boundaries, so that each mapper can process the individual InputSplit in parallel. For ex., an input table has 1000 rows, then it can be split **logically** into 10 InputSplits saying 1-100 rows belong to InputSplit-1, 101-200 belong to InputSplit-2 and so on. Similarly, a 1GB file can be split into multiple 128MB blocks, to be processed in parallel. **Logical** is the key word in this context.